# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "xgboost" error for installed package in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, xgboost, modulenotfounderror

I am working on a jupyter notebook, and I need to install a package "xgboost" that was not in the conda environment that the notebook was running.

After installed, I tried to do

```
import xgboost
```

and got the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost'
```

You can see that the package was installed already while still got this error.
My python verion is `python3.8` and I am using macbook. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting your notebook after you installed the package?

Comment: I did and unfortunately it does not work. Meanwhile if it works, it is not an ideal solution since it would be weird that I need to restart the notebook whenever I want to install a package. That means one need to quite the working history when he/she want to install a package.

Comment: Probably `pip` is pointing to a different environment or even installing to the system's python. You can try the magic `%pip` instead [docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pip).

Comment: Hi @josemz , it works well. Thanks for saving me.